# C++ STL Vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I need to write a program to use an STL vector large enough to hold a user-defined number of test scores. Once all the numbers are entered, I need to average the test scores and sort them in ascending order. The issue I am having is after I put in the number of scores I am going to put in, no matter what numbers scores I put in, it reads only the first one then uses that as an average and the ascending order is pretty much that number times how many scores I put in next to each other. This is what I have so far. Thank you for any help!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

float Average (vector<int> scores, int number);
void SortTestScores(vector<int> scores, int n);

void main(){

    vector<int> testScores;
    float averageScore, score;

    int number, i;

    cout << "Enter number of test scores: ";
    cin >> number;

    cout << "Enter test scores: ";
    for (i = 0; i < number; i++){
        cin >> score;
        testScores.push_back(score);
    }

    SortTestScores(testScores, number);

    cout << "Sorted test scores: ";
    for (i = 0; i < number; i++){
        cout << testScores.at(i);
    }

    averageScore = Average(testScores, number);

    cout << "Average test score is: " << averageScore << endl;
    system("pause");
}

//sort function

void SortTestScores(vector<int> scores, int number){
    int temp; //temporary variable
    int i, j; //loop variables
    for (i = 1; i < number; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < number - i; j++){
            if (scores.at(j) > scores.at(j+1)){
                temp = scores.at(j);
                scores.at(j) = scores.at (j+1);
                scores.at(j+1) = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

float Average(vector<int> score, int n){
    int i; 
    float avg = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        avg+=score.at(i);
    }
    avg = avg/n;
    return avg;
}
```

Comment: When `SortTestScores` is called, you are passing a copy of the vector. If you want to change the data in main you need to pas the vector by reference. In `Average` you should probably pass as a cost reference for efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
void SortTestScores(vector<int> scores, int number);
```

to

```
void SortTestScores(vector<int> &scores, int number);
```

so that the vector is passed by reference and the changes made in the function stay in the original vector. Alternatively you can use:

```
vector<int> SortTestScores(vector<int> scores, int number);
testScores = SortTestScores(testScores, number);
```

returning the sorted vector and assigning it to the original, but it will be quite inefficient.
Also, if you are using c++11, you can use:
    std::sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end());
for very efficient sorting (Timsort).

Comment: `std::sort` is not limited to c++11

Comment: `testScores = SortTestScores(std::move(testScores), number)` will be as efficient as the pass-by reference